# Blazor WASM block Task until user input

Tags: multithreading, modal-dialog, blazor, webassembly

I need to implement a class interface with the following method signature:

```
 bool GetChoice<T>(string title, string body, out T chosen, params T[] options);
```

In console or desktop app I would do:

```
 return Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

or

```
 var dlg = new MyDialogueBox(options);
 dlg.ShowDialog();
 return dlg.Result;
```

I have a textbox in which the user can enter commands so I thought it would be pretty simple to block and wait for the user to enter the choice into the text box (or throw up some buttons and block until one was pressed).

My method currently looks like:

```
while(true)
{
    Task.Delay(10);
    // Check textbox for choice being entered

    // return choice if one has been made

    // I had hoped this call would pump the UI thread but it doesn't
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

I know Blazor doesn't support threads yet (and WASM threading in  general is a very new feature).  But there is a lot of talk of tasks and yielding the thread (back to the UI?).  But as soon I trigger the method the whole UI blocks up.

I've seen other threads about this issue (Task.Delay) but no solutions other than breaking up a long running task - which I can't do here since what I want is blocking until a condition.

I start the process running using a button press:

```
  Task round = new Task(()=>
      {
        // This will trigger 0 or more calls to GetChoice
        world.RunRound(ui,a);

        StateHasChanged();
      });

      round.Start();
```

Is there any way in Blazor to make this work? Or do I have to wait till they implement Threads?

Comment: That's the wrong kind of interface in _any_ GUI app. Which makes this look like an XY question. Who calls GetChoice() and how does the flow go after that?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  GetChoice is called arbitrarily during `world.RunRound()` depending on the state of the world and what occurs during the round.  Why is the interface 'wrong'? its a method to illicit a modal choice from the user?  The interface is exposed from a turn based text heavy game engine that doesn't want to know anything about the GUI but wants to be able to get answers from it about what the user wants to do as it advances the round.

Comment: Sounds like it came from a Console type app. You now have 2 toplevel loops, that's not going to work well. Consider making the game loop a statemachine where you can push steps.

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped to avoid that :( there are implicit choices made in the UI before `RunRound` (which action to and targets to start the round with) but I liked being able to call out during the round arbitrarily (it is a console style engine your right).  At least the action and round are quite atomic and stateful already so thats a start.